# Fluent Interface - How to hide members (property setters) if they are already set?

Tags: c#, fluent, fluent-interface

I am taking a stab at writing a fluent API in C#. What I am trying to do is make a builder that can set some properties. The properties can be set in any order, and all of them are optional. After a property is already set, it makes little sense to still show the method that sets it in intellisense, so I would like to hide it if it is already set. Here is an example of the type of API I would like with just 3 properties.

```
public interface ISoldier
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Rank { get; set; }
    int SerialNumber { get; set; }
}

public interface ISoldierBuilder
{
    IInterrogationStarter InterrogateSoldier();
}

public interface IInterrogationEnder
{
    ISoldier FinishInterrogation();
}

// No properties set (3 that can still be set)
public interface IInterrogationStarter : IInterrogationEnder
{
    IBuilderWithNameSet WithName(string value);
    IBuilderWithRankSet WithRank(string value);
    IBuilderWithSerialNumberSet WithSerialNumber(int value);
}

// One property set (2 that can still be set)
public interface IBuilderWithNameSet : IInterrogationEnder
{
    IBuilderWithNameAndRankSet WithRank(string value);
    IBuilderWithNameAndSerialNumberSet WithSerialNumber(int value);
}

public interface IBuilderWithRankSet : IInterrogationEnder
{
    IBuilderWithNameAndRankSet WithName(string value);
    IBuilderWithRankAndSerialNumberSet WithSerialNumber(int value);
}

public interface IBuilderWithSerialNumberSet : IInterrogationEnder
{
    IBuilderWithNameAndSerialNumberSet WithName(string value);
    IBuilderWithRankAndSerialNumberSet WithRank(string value);
}

// Two properties set (1 that can still be set)
public interface IBuilderWithNameAndRankSet : IInterrogationEnder
{
    IInterrogationEnder WithSerialNumber(int value);
}

public interface IBuilderWithNameAndSerialNumberSet : IInterrogationEnder
{
    IInterrogationEnder WithRank(string value);
}

public interface IBuilderWithRankAndSerialNumberSet : IInterrogationEnder
{
    IInterrogationEnder WithName(string value);
}
```

I left off the implementation because it isn't required to demonstrate what I am trying to do. Now, if you actually copy this code into a project you can see what I am trying to do. Once a property is set, it is no longer available in the list in intellisense.

```
ISoldierBuilder builder;

ISoldier soldier1 = builder.InterrogateSoldier()
    .WithName("Bob")
    .WithRank("Corporal")
    .FinishInterrogation();

ISoldier soldier2 = builder.InterrogateSoldier()
    .WithSerialNumber(12345)
    .FinishInterrogation();

ISoldier soldier3 = builder.InterrogateSoldier()
    .WithRank("Captain")
    .WithSerialNumber(55533)
    .WithName("John")
    .FinishInterrogation();
```

For example, with soldier1, once we call .WithName("Bob").WithRank("Corporal"), all that is left in the available choices are:

```
WithSerialNumber
FinishInterrogation
```

Setting the name again would just be confusing - which one is the actual name we need to put into the ISoldier instance?

Now imagine trying to expand this simple example to 10 properties. My question is - how can I make my optional properties disappear from intellisense after they are set without creating a huge number of interfaces that grow exponentially with the number of properties?

**More Context**

The goals of the fluent API are to make it easier to write, easier to read, and to enforce business rules. If we haven't accomplished those, then there is little point in creating a fluent API.

**The Long Story**

In my research, I discovered that the definition of a fluent interface is one where the words flow together into a sentence and can be spoken aloud. However, in practice true fluent APIs are quite rare because of the amount of extra work they require to implement. A typical compromise is to make one that is easily readable, but doesn't necessarily make sense to speak aloud.

I would like to go a little bit beyond that because in my own experience with existing fluent API implementations - I find that they are usually difficult to use and require quite a bit of research to learn how to configure. So I am adding an additional constraint that the API must be as easy to work with - preferably by discovering the available options using intellisense.

Also, I discovered that one of the most compelling reasons to use a fluent API is the ability to enforce some business rules at the compiler level. I read [some](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2013/12/01/Best-Practices-for-Designing-a-Fluent-API.aspx?Page=1) [great](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/01/01/strategies-and-code-for-creating-fluent-apis.aspx) [articles](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/11/01/when-to-build-fluent-interfaces-for-re-use-and-clarity.aspx) by Peter Vogel that go into some details about how to enforce business rules and used some of these techniques to enforce [13 of the business rules](https://github.com/NightOwl888/MvcSiteMapProvider_FluentApiDemo1/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider_FluentApiDemo1/ReadMe.txt) I need for my application in a way that won't compile unless the rules are followed. This is the best argument yet for using a fluent API, as just making an API that is readable is nothing more than syntactic sugar, but ensuring business rules are enforced is a much more practical and functional use.

Furthermore, "readability" is subjective and depends on who you anticipate to read the API. I am willing to make a few compromises here because the intended audience are developers.

The back story is that I have already implemented a [non-functional prototype](https://github.com/NightOwl888/MvcSiteMapProvider_FluentApiDemo1/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider_FluentApiDemo1/_FluentSiteMapNodeProviders/SemanticSiteMapNodeProvider.cs) that enforces several of the business rules I have, as well as changes properties depending on their context because they are used differently when the context changes. I am hoping there is some way to use generics, attributes, or some other compiler magic to solve this one extra business rule without having to make dozens of extra interfaces to support it, and then have to change all of those interfaces when a new property is added.

The fluent API is also going to be an alternative to XML for semantically marking up a hierarchy of objects, which is yet another compelling argument for its usage. Some of the business rules (which haven't yet been implemented) deal with property inheritance from parent objects to their descendant objects.

[Using the prototype to load data from a dynamic data source](https://github.com/NightOwl888/MvcSiteMapProvider_FluentApiDemo1/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider_FluentApiDemo1/_FluentSiteMapNodeProviders/DynamicSiteMapNodeProvider.cs)

Answer (score 2):

> My question is - how can I make my optional properties disappear from intellisense after they are set without creating a huge number of interfaces that grow exponentially with the number of properties?

You can't with your current approach, and I wouldn't try to.

One alternative is to use a builder type with *properties* instead of methods - that way when you use an object initializer, the *compiler* will stop you from setting a property more than once. So:

```
var soldier = new Soldier.Builder { 
    SerialNumber = 12345,
    Name = "John",
    Rank = Rank.Captain // I'd use an enum for the ranks...
}.Build();
```

Half way through the object initializer, Intellisense will only prompt for the properties that haven't been set, but

In other cases where there are *required* properties, you can put those in the constructor and use named arguments for clarity:

```
var soldier = new Solider.Builder(name: "John", serialNumber: 12345) {
    Rank = Rank.Captain,
    SomeOtherOptionalProperty = "some value"
}.Build();
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of this approach. However, I guess I should have been more clear about what I am trying to do. I updated my question. I don't think this counts as being easy to read (certainly property setters are not read like plain English and we have lost the interrogation intent altogether) or easy to write (you would probably have to consult the documentation to figure out where the optional properties are), it simply enforces the business rule that they can only be set once.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I think we must have different ideas about readability. I'd rather use properties than methods here, and in terms of discoverability they're just as good as methods - better in fact, as the methods inherited from object won't be displayed. You can obviously change Build to FinishInterrogation if you really want, but that doesn't feel particularly appropriate to me for the builder pattern.

Comment: I have other business rules to be concerned with, as well. PropertyA cannot be used in conjunction with PropertyB, required properties, cannot use a dictionary property at the same time as a collection property, etc. I don't see a clear path to how this can be done with this approach. I also really don't see the point in using the builder at all if using this approach because we have gained nothing over ISoldier except extra stuff to maintain, or is there something I am missing?

Comment: @NightOwl888: The point of the builder pattern is usually to build an immutable type. For business rules, I'd probably put that checking in the Build/FinishInterrogation method. To be honest, I don't think we have enough context to give you an answer that will satisfy you, particularly if you keep adding extra requirements.

Comment: Sorry, I was intentionally oversimplifying the problem to focus on this one aspect of it - setting the optional properties only once.

Comment: @NightOwl888: then I'd use properties for the properties, and make the building method return something with appropriate other methods.

Comment: It might work if there is a reasonable way to combine the approaches. Could you please update your answer to show how you would actually implement Soldier.Builder? FYI - I have added the entire back story to my question as well as a link to a configuration using the latest prototype and a link to a list of all of the business rules it currently enforces.

Comment: @NightOwl888: Will look later. Can't really edit now.